# Trazer múltiplos dados

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu tenho esse select, a intenção dele é ele me retornar os kits que contenham esses ids obrigatoriamente (pode conter mais produtos mas esses precisam estar), (556, 557,534, 558, 1224, 805) e não retornar esses ids (420, 419). Porém com IN, ele está trazendo dados que não contenham os itens obrigatórios.

```
select distinct 
    
        ctl_produto_lista.cpli_cpro_id_master as "Id Kit",
        cad_produto.cpro_nome as "Kit",
        cad_produto.cpro_descricao as "Descrição"
        
from ctl_produto_lista 

left join cad_produto

where cpli_cpro_id_item in (556, 557,534, 558, 1224, 805)

and cpli_cpro_id_item not in (420, 419);
```

Comment: se fizer o primeiro `in`, já não vai trazer o que tem no segundo, ele é desnecessário (se diz **só** me traz 1,2,3  não precisa dizer **não me traz** 4,5,6). O problema ai é o join, vc só disse `left join cad_produto` e não informa a expressão diz por qual campo as tabelas estão ligadas, sugiro estudar como funciona o join (join, left join, right join, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Você está relacionando a tabela ctl_produto_lista com cad_produto mas esse relacionamento está errado.

Você precisa dizer que o ctl_produto_lista.cod_produto é igual a cad_produto.cod_produto

ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
select ctl_produto_lista.cpli_cpro_id_master as "Id Kit",
       cad_produto.cpro_nome as "Kit",
       cad_produto.cpro_descricao as "Descrição" 
  from ctl_produto_lista left join cad_produto on (cad_produto.cod_produto = ctl_produto_lista .cpli_cpro_id_item)
 where cpli_cpro_id_item in (556, 557,534, 558, 1224, 805);
```

Quando você faz uma consulta IN não é necessário fazer NOT IN pois você já limitou quais são os códigos que você vai buscar no IN.

O NOT IN seria usado caso você queira busca todos os registro menos 420 e 419.

Espero ter ajudado.